# Remote Validation on multiple fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to validate that `Ville` + `Code-postal` + `Pays` are unique.

If validation does not pass, I would like to mark fields as invalid (red as usually).

[image]

I already try a first implementation like below:

```
public class CityEditViewModel
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }

    [Required, Remote("CityAlreadyExists", "City", AdditionalFields = "CountryID, CityID, PostCode", ErrorMessageResourceName = "CityAlreadyExists", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    [Display(Name = "City", ResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    [Required, Remote("CityAlreadyExists", "City", AdditionalFields = "CountryID, CityID, CityName", ErrorMessageResourceName = "CityAlreadyExists", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    [Display(Name = "PostCode", ResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [Required, Remote("CityAlreadyExists", "City", AdditionalFields = "CityName, PostCode, CityID", ErrorMessageResourceName = "CityAlreadyExists", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    [Display(Name = "Country", ResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

But all the fields are not checked (validate) until I really change something in it. I need a solution where every time I change one of the 3 fields, the all 3 fields are validated and marked in red if needed.

I already check other Stackoverflow posts but did not found a solution to my specific problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have exactly the same scenario - did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar scenario too, this one helped me get going

```
$("#FirstName").change(function () {
        $('#CardNumber').removeData('previousValue');
        $('#CardNumber').valid();
  });
```

[Multiple fields validation using Remote Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163683/remote-validation-mvc-3-0-multiple-fields-validation)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it asap and keep you informed.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Suchan's answer, I wrote this helper method that finds each remotely validating element that has "additional fields," and then causes validation on said element to fire each time one of those fields changes.

```js
// I hate naming things
function initializeRemotelyValidatingElementsWithAdditionalFields($form) {
    var remotelyValidatingElements = $form.find("[data-val-remote]");

    $.each(remotelyValidatingElements, function (i, element) {
        var $element = $(element);

        var additionalFields = $element.attr("data-val-remote-additionalfields");

        if (additionalFields.length == 0) return;

        var rawFieldNames = additionalFields.split(",");

        var fieldNames = $.map(rawFieldNames, function (fieldName) { return fieldName.replace("*.", ""); });

        $.each(fieldNames, function (i, fieldName) {
            $form.find("#" + fieldName).change(function () {
                // force re-validation to occur
                $element.removeData("previousValue");
                $element.valid();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Call the function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initializeRemotelyValidatingElementsWithAdditionalFields($("#myFormId"));
});
```