# MVC Remote Validation - Clear or set additional field errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reset, remote-validation

We have 2 input textfields on the screen whose combination makes up a valid entry.  We are doing remote validation on both of them.

Our ViewModel:

```
[Remote("IsExampleValid", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Field2")]
public int Field1 { get; set; }

[Remote("IsExampleValid", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Field1")]
public int Field2 { get; set; }
```

The problem is these still fire separately and do not truly act together like we need.  For example, if I enter bad data in both of them to make an invalid entry then they both will have an error.  If I change Field2 to make a valid combination, the remote validation method will get called and mark Field2 as valid.  However, Field1 will still be invalid.  Field1 should be valid though because they are a combination.  Is there a better way to do 2 fields that make up a valid combination?

Comment: Have you considered implementing `IValidatableObject` on your ViewModel?

Comment: IValidatableObject will work to validate on submit, but can IValidatableObject validate immediately like remote validation can?  We need immediate feedback.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this awesome piece of code [provided by Kiff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747858/114029):

```
function initializeRemotelyValidatingElementsWithAdditionalFields($form) {
    var remotelyValidatingElements = $form.find("[data-val-remote]");

    $.each(remotelyValidatingElements, function (i, element) {
        var $element = $(element);

        var additionalFields = $element.attr("data-val-remote-additionalfields");

        if (additionalFields.length == 0) return;

        var rawFieldNames = additionalFields.split(",");

        var fieldNames = $.map(rawFieldNames, function (fieldName) { return fieldName.replace("*.", ""); });

        $.each(fieldNames, function (i, fieldName) {
            $form.find("[id$="+fieldName+"]").change(function () {
                 if ($element.is(':enabled'))
                 {
                     // force re-validation to occur
                     $element.removeData("previousValue");

                     $element.valid();
                 }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Call the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initializeRemotelyValidatingElementsWithAdditionalFields($("form"));
});
```

Note: I adapted the `$form.find` portion so that it works when one is using [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) in which case element `IDs` are prefixed. I also added the `$element.is(':enabled')` check so that validation will only fire if the element is currently enabled on the page.

Answer (score 1):

MVC Remote Validation - Clear or set additional field errors

```
public int Field1 { get; set; }

    [Remote("IsExampleValid", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Field1")]
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
```

jquery code here

```
$('#Field1').on('change', function () {
       //code
        $('#Field2').removeData('previousValue');
    });
```

it's Working additionalField value change after remote validation check isvalid or not